# Are these statements equal? PHP Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

My question has two parts. First question, is it ok to assign a multidimensional array in this fashion:

```
$sandwhich => array(
    'bread', 'meat', 'tomato'
);
$cereal => array(
    'milk', 'cherrios', 'bannana'
);
$food = array(
    $sandwhich, $cereal
);
```

And my second question is, would the `$food` array above be equivalent to:

```
$food = array(
    $sandwhich => array(
        'bread', 'meat', 'tomato'
    ) 
    $cereal => array(
        'milk', 'cherrios', 'bannana'
    )
);
```

Thank you,

Comment: If you want to know if 2 arrays are equals, just do: `var_dump($array1 === $array2);`

Comment: say print_r in both cases to watch the result

Comment: 1. Yes, it's okay if you need it. 2. You could simply call them $food1 and $food2 and then compare if they are equivalent.

Comment: Try running it to see if `$sandwhich => array(
    'bread', 'meat', 'tomato'
);` is [valid syntax](https://3v4l.org/fgPTJ)

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I do not have a server to test this on, hence the question.

Comment: You really ought to get a server to test this on -- At least a locally running one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they're not equivalent...

The first one just defines an array that contains two other arrays, each of which contains 3 strings. It's no different than if you'd written out, in full.

```
$food = array();
$food[0] = array();
$food[0][0] = 'bread';
$food[0][1] = 'meat';
etc...
$food[1][2] = 'bannana';
```

The second one would trigger `undefined variable`, since you haven't defined `$sandwich` or `$cereal`, and you'd be assignin your two sub-arrays to an empty-string key:

```
$food = array(
  "" => array(...),
  "" => array(...)
);
```

Since those two keys are the same (empty strings), you'll end up with an array containing ONE other array, the last one you added in.

And if `$sandwich` or `$cereal` were defined as arrays previously, then you'd get an illegal offset type warning and end up with an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

First of all we can't assign with `=>`, we use the operator `=` instead.

for the first part, this is the correct syntaxe:

```
$sandwhich = array('bread', 'meat', 'tomato');

$cereal = array('milk', 'cherrios', 'bannana');

$food = array();
$food[] = $sandwhich;
$food[] = $cereal;
```

for the second part:

```
$food = array(
    'sandwich' => array('bread', 'meat', 'tomato'), 
    'cereal' => array('milk', 'cherrios', 'bannana')
);
```